# Trying to figure out how to use Puppeteer to extract a collection of DOM elements based on a class name

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

The web page that I am scraping has several DIV elements that have the CSS class name of '*s-suggestion*'.

I'm looking to get *dataset* values out of these elements.

I have the following line of code in my script (running on node.js):

`const suggestions = await page.$$eval('.s-suggestion',(divs) => divs);`

When I look at the value of `suggestions.length` it is 10.

Now the following code:

```
        for (let n=0;n<suggestions.length;n++) {
            const suggestion = suggestions[n];
            console.log("n="+n)
            
            // line below outputs value of:   undefined 
            console.log("   - suggestion className: "+suggestion.className);

            // line commented out below is approx. what I'd like to have:
            // const sKeyword = suggestion.dataset.keyword
        } // next n
```

The values returned for the className are all *undefined* .

I don't think these objects are DOM nodes!

BTW: These DIVs have the same className in question but not some unique id that I would know before-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) and alike ones can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). As `await page.$$eval('.s-suggestion',(divs) => divs);` returns a collection of DOM elements that are not serializable (they contain methods and circular references), each element in the collection is replaced with an empty object or `undefined`. You need to return either serializable value (for example, an array of texts or attributes) or use something like [`page.$$(selector)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) and [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) API.

For your case, try:

```js
const keywords = await page.$$eval(
  '.s-suggestion',
  divs => Array.from(divs, div => div.dataset.keyword),
);
```